# MongoDB query for java Calendar instance

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is Spring model class as below, and am using Spring data module to persist the documents in `attachment` collection

```
@Document(collection = "attachment")
class Attachment {

@Id
private String id

private String fileName, attachment

private Calendar createdAt, updatedAt
}
```

Below is the value of `createdAt` in the mongo db (`version 3.4.14`)

I'm not sure how to query for java Calendar instance in mongo, with `createdAt` value greater than `2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`, can someone please help me with it?

```
createdAt:{  
      "_class":"java.util.GregorianCalendar",
      "gregorianCutover":NumberLong(-12219292800000),
      "gregorianCutoverDate":NumberLong(577736),
      "gregorianCutoverYear":1582,
      "gregorianCutoverYearJulian":1582,
      "gdate":{  
         "_class":"sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date",
         "cachedYear":2018,
         "cachedFixedDateJan1":NumberLong(736695),
         "cachedFixedDateNextJan1":NumberLong(737060),
         "year":2018,
         "month":3,
         "dayOfMonth":12,
         "dayOfWeek":2,
         "leapYear":false,
         "hours":0,
         "minutes":0,
         "seconds":0,
         "millis":0,
         "fraction":NumberLong(0),
         "normalized":true,
         "zoneinfo":{  
            "_class":"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo",
            "rawOffset":-28800000,
            "rawOffsetDiff":0,
            "checksum":-2115702508,
            "dstSavings":3600000,
            "transitions":[  
               NumberLong(-9048018124800000),
               NumberLong(-6689872281599967),
               NumberLong(-6615569203200000),
               NumberLong(-6561054719999967),
               NumberLong(-6486751641600000),
               NumberLong(-3605328691199967),
               NumberLong(-3135017779200000),
               NumberLong(-2817913651199967),
               NumberLong(-2714237337600000),
               NumberLong(-2542937702399967),
               NumberLong(-2490929971200000),
               NumberLong(-2414120140799967),
               NumberLong(-2359635148800000),
               NumberLong(-2285302579199967),
               NumberLong(-2230817587200000),
               NumberLong(-2156485017599967),
               NumberLong(-2102000025600000),
               NumberLong(-2027667455999967),
               NumberLong(-1973182464000000),
               NumberLong(-1898849894399967),
               NumberLong(-1844364902400000),
               NumberLong(-1767555071999967),
               NumberLong(-1713070080000000),
               NumberLong(-1638737510399967),
               NumberLong(-1584252518400000),
               NumberLong(-1509919948799967),
               NumberLong(-1455434956800000),
               NumberLong(-1381102387199967),
               NumberLong(-1326617395200000),
               NumberLong(-1252284825599967),
               NumberLong(-1197799833600000),
               NumberLong(-1120990003199967),
               NumberLong(-1068982272000000),
               NumberLong(-992172441599967),
               NumberLong(-927778406400000),
               NumberLong(-863354879999967),
               NumberLong(-798960844800000),
               NumberLong(-734537318399967),
               NumberLong(-670143283200000),
               NumberLong(-605719756799967),
               NumberLong(-538848460800000),
               NumberLong(-476902195199967),
               NumberLong(-410030899200000),
               NumberLong(-345607372799967),
               NumberLong(-281213337600000),
               NumberLong(-216789811199967),
               NumberLong(-152395776000000),
               NumberLong(-87972249599967),
               NumberLong(-23578214400000),
               NumberLong(40845312000033),
               NumberLong(105239347200000),
               NumberLong(169662873600033),
               NumberLong(236534169600000),
               NumberLong(300957696000033),
               NumberLong(365351731200000),
               NumberLong(429775257600033),
               NumberLong(494169292800000),
               NumberLong(518956646400033),
               NumberLong(622986854400000),
               NumberLong(665115033600033),
               NumberLong(751804416000000),
               NumberLong(816227942400033),
               NumberLong(883099238400000),
               NumberLong(945045504000033),
               NumberLong(1011916800000000),
               NumberLong(1076340326400033),
               NumberLong(1140734361600000),
               NumberLong(1205157888000033),
               NumberLong(1269551923200000),
               NumberLong(1333975449600033),
               NumberLong(1398369484800000),
               NumberLong(1462793011200033),
               NumberLong(1527187046400000),
               NumberLong(1591610572800033),
               NumberLong(1658481868800000),
               NumberLong(1720428134400033),
               NumberLong(1787299430400000),
               NumberLong(1851722956800033),
               NumberLong(1916116992000000),
               NumberLong(1980540518400033),
               NumberLong(2044934553600000),
               NumberLong(2109358080000033),
               NumberLong(2173752115200000),
               NumberLong(2230743859200033),
               NumberLong(2302569676800000),
               NumberLong(2359561420800033),
               NumberLong(2433864499200000),
               NumberLong(2488378982400033),
               NumberLong(2562682060800000),
               NumberLong(2617196544000033),
               NumberLong(2691499622400000),
               NumberLong(2748491366400033),
               NumberLong(2820317184000000),
               NumberLong(2877308928000033),
               NumberLong(2949134745600000),
               NumberLong(3006126489600033),
               NumberLong(3080429568000000),
               NumberLong(3134944051200033),
               NumberLong(3209247129600000),
               NumberLong(3263761612800033),
               NumberLong(3338064691200000),
               NumberLong(3395056435200033),
               NumberLong(3466882252800000),
               NumberLong(3523873996800033),
               NumberLong(3595699814400000),
               NumberLong(3652691558400033),
               NumberLong(3724517376000000),
               NumberLong(3781509120000033),
               NumberLong(3855812198400000),
               NumberLong(3910326681600033),
               NumberLong(3984629760000000),
               NumberLong(4039144243200033),
               NumberLong(4113447321600000),
               NumberLong(4170439065600033),
               NumberLong(4242264883200000),
               NumberLong(4299256627200033),
               NumberLong(4371082444800000),
               NumberLong(4428074188800033),
               NumberLong(4502377267200000),
               NumberLong(4556891750400033),
               NumberLong(4631194828800000),
               NumberLong(4685709312000033),
               NumberLong(4760012390400000),
               NumberLong(4807095091200033),
               NumberLong(4891307212800000),
               NumberLong(4935912652800033),
               NumberLong(5020124774400000),
               NumberLong(5064730214400033),
               NumberLong(5148942336000000),
               NumberLong(5196025036800033),
               NumberLong(5280237158400000),
               NumberLong(5324842598400033),
               NumberLong(5409054720000000),
               NumberLong(5453660160000033),
               NumberLong(5537872281600000),
               NumberLong(5582477721600033),
               NumberLong(5666689843200000),
               NumberLong(5711295283200033),
               NumberLong(5795507404800000),
               NumberLong(5840112844800033),
               NumberLong(5924324966400000),
               NumberLong(5971407667200033),
               NumberLong(6055619788800000),
               NumberLong(6100225228800033),
               NumberLong(6184437350400000),
               NumberLong(6229042790400033),
               NumberLong(6313254912000000),
               NumberLong(6357860352000033),
               NumberLong(6442072473600000),
               NumberLong(6486677913600033),
               NumberLong(6570890035200000),
               NumberLong(6617972736000033),
               NumberLong(6702184857600000),
               NumberLong(6746790297600033),
               NumberLong(6831002419200000),
               NumberLong(6875607859200033),
               NumberLong(6959819980800000),
               NumberLong(7004425420800033),
               NumberLong(7088637542400000),
               NumberLong(7133242982400033),
               NumberLong(7217455104000000),
               NumberLong(7262060544000033),
               NumberLong(7346272665600000),
               NumberLong(7393355366400033),
               NumberLong(7477567488000000),
               NumberLong(7522172928000033),
               NumberLong(7606385049600000),
               NumberLong(7650990489600033),
               NumberLong(7735202611200000),
               NumberLong(7779808051200033),
               NumberLong(7864020172800000),
               NumberLong(7908625612800033),
               NumberLong(7992837734400000),
               NumberLong(8039920435200033),
               NumberLong(8124132556800000),
               NumberLong(8168737996800033),
               NumberLong(8252950118400000),
               NumberLong(8297555558400033),
               NumberLong(8381767680000000),
               NumberLong(8426373120000033),
               NumberLong(8510585241600000),
               NumberLong(8555190681600033),
               NumberLong(8639402803200000),
               NumberLong(8684008243200033),
               NumberLong(8768220364800000)
            ],
            "offsets":[  
               -28800000,
               -25200000,
               3600000
            ],
            "simpleTimeZoneParams":[  
               2,
               8,
               -1,
               7200000,
               0,
               10,
               1,
               -1,
               7200000,
               0
            ],
            "willGMTOffsetChange":false,
            "dirty":false,
            "ID":"America/Los_Angeles"
         },
         "zoneOffset":0,
         "daylightSaving":0,
         "forceStandardTime":false
      },
      "cdate":{  
         "_class":"sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date",
         "cachedYear":2018,
         "cachedFixedDateJan1":NumberLong(736695),
         "cachedFixedDateNextJan1":NumberLong(737060),
         "year":2018,
         "month":3,
         "dayOfMonth":12,
         "dayOfWeek":2,
         "leapYear":false,
         "hours":0,
         "minutes":0,
         "seconds":0,
         "millis":0,
         "fraction":NumberLong(0),
         "normalized":true,
         "zoneinfo":{  
            "_class":"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo",
            "rawOffset":-28800000,
            "rawOffsetDiff":0,
            "checksum":-2115702508,
            "dstSavings":3600000,
            "transitions":[  
               NumberLong(-9048018124800000),
               NumberLong(-6689872281599967),
               NumberLong(-6615569203200000),
               NumberLong(-6561054719999967),
               NumberLong(-6486751641600000),
               NumberLong(-3605328691199967),
               NumberLong(-3135017779200000),
               NumberLong(-2817913651199967),
               NumberLong(-2714237337600000),
               NumberLong(-2542937702399967),
               NumberLong(-2490929971200000),
               NumberLong(-2414120140799967),
               NumberLong(-2359635148800000),
               NumberLong(-2285302579199967),
               NumberLong(-2230817587200000),
               NumberLong(-2156485017599967),
               NumberLong(-2102000025600000),
               NumberLong(-2027667455999967),
               NumberLong(-1973182464000000),
               NumberLong(-1898849894399967),
               NumberLong(-1844364902400000),
               NumberLong(-1767555071999967),
               NumberLong(-1713070080000000),
               NumberLong(-1638737510399967),
               NumberLong(-1584252518400000),
               NumberLong(-1509919948799967),
               NumberLong(-1455434956800000),
               NumberLong(-1381102387199967),
               NumberLong(-1326617395200000),
               NumberLong(-1252284825599967),
               NumberLong(-1197799833600000),
               NumberLong(-1120990003199967),
               NumberLong(-1068982272000000),
               NumberLong(-992172441599967),
               NumberLong(-927778406400000),
               NumberLong(-863354879999967),
               NumberLong(-798960844800000),
               NumberLong(-734537318399967),
               NumberLong(-670143283200000),
               NumberLong(-605719756799967),
               NumberLong(-538848460800000),
               NumberLong(-476902195199967),
               NumberLong(-410030899200000),
               NumberLong(-345607372799967),
               NumberLong(-281213337600000),
               NumberLong(-216789811199967),
               NumberLong(-152395776000000),
               NumberLong(-87972249599967),
               NumberLong(-23578214400000),
               NumberLong(40845312000033),
               NumberLong(105239347200000),
               NumberLong(169662873600033),
               NumberLong(236534169600000),
               NumberLong(300957696000033),
               NumberLong(365351731200000),
               NumberLong(429775257600033),
               NumberLong(494169292800000),
               NumberLong(518956646400033),
               NumberLong(622986854400000),
               NumberLong(665115033600033),
               NumberLong(751804416000000),
               NumberLong(816227942400033),
               NumberLong(883099238400000),
               NumberLong(945045504000033),
               NumberLong(1011916800000000),
               NumberLong(1076340326400033),
               NumberLong(1140734361600000),
               NumberLong(1205157888000033),
               NumberLong(1269551923200000),
               NumberLong(1333975449600033),
               NumberLong(1398369484800000),
               NumberLong(1462793011200033),
               NumberLong(1527187046400000),
               NumberLong(1591610572800033),
               NumberLong(1658481868800000),
               NumberLong(1720428134400033),
               NumberLong(1787299430400000),
               NumberLong(1851722956800033),
               NumberLong(1916116992000000),
               NumberLong(1980540518400033),
               NumberLong(2044934553600000),
               NumberLong(2109358080000033),
               NumberLong(2173752115200000),
               NumberLong(2230743859200033),
               NumberLong(2302569676800000),
               NumberLong(2359561420800033),
               NumberLong(2433864499200000),
               NumberLong(2488378982400033),
               NumberLong(2562682060800000),
               NumberLong(2617196544000033),
               NumberLong(2691499622400000),
               NumberLong(2748491366400033),
               NumberLong(2820317184000000),
               NumberLong(2877308928000033),
               NumberLong(2949134745600000),
               NumberLong(3006126489600033),
               NumberLong(3080429568000000),
               NumberLong(3134944051200033),
               NumberLong(3209247129600000),
               NumberLong(3263761612800033),
               NumberLong(3338064691200000),
               NumberLong(3395056435200033),
               NumberLong(3466882252800000),
               NumberLong(3523873996800033),
               NumberLong(3595699814400000),
               NumberLong(3652691558400033),
               NumberLong(3724517376000000),
               NumberLong(3781509120000033),
               NumberLong(3855812198400000),
               NumberLong(3910326681600033),
               NumberLong(3984629760000000),
               NumberLong(4039144243200033),
               NumberLong(4113447321600000),
               NumberLong(4170439065600033),
               NumberLong(4242264883200000),
               NumberLong(4299256627200033),
               NumberLong(4371082444800000),
               NumberLong(4428074188800033),
               NumberLong(4502377267200000),
               NumberLong(4556891750400033),
               NumberLong(4631194828800000),
               NumberLong(4685709312000033),
               NumberLong(4760012390400000),
               NumberLong(4807095091200033),
               NumberLong(4891307212800000),
               NumberLong(4935912652800033),
               NumberLong(5020124774400000),
               NumberLong(5064730214400033),
               NumberLong(5148942336000000),
               NumberLong(5196025036800033),
               NumberLong(5280237158400000),
               NumberLong(5324842598400033),
               NumberLong(5409054720000000),
               NumberLong(5453660160000033),
               NumberLong(5537872281600000),
               NumberLong(5582477721600033),
               NumberLong(5666689843200000),
               NumberLong(5711295283200033),
               NumberLong(5795507404800000),
               NumberLong(5840112844800033),
               NumberLong(5924324966400000),
               NumberLong(5971407667200033),
               NumberLong(6055619788800000),
               NumberLong(6100225228800033),
               NumberLong(6184437350400000),
               NumberLong(6229042790400033),
               NumberLong(6313254912000000),
               NumberLong(6357860352000033),
               NumberLong(6442072473600000),
               NumberLong(6486677913600033),
               NumberLong(6570890035200000),
               NumberLong(6617972736000033),
               NumberLong(6702184857600000),
               NumberLong(6746790297600033),
               NumberLong(6831002419200000),
               NumberLong(6875607859200033),
               NumberLong(6959819980800000),
               NumberLong(7004425420800033),
               NumberLong(7088637542400000),
               NumberLong(7133242982400033),
               NumberLong(7217455104000000),
               NumberLong(7262060544000033),
               NumberLong(7346272665600000),
               NumberLong(7393355366400033),
               NumberLong(7477567488000000),
               NumberLong(7522172928000033),
               NumberLong(7606385049600000),
               NumberLong(7650990489600033),
               NumberLong(7735202611200000),
               NumberLong(7779808051200033),
               NumberLong(7864020172800000),
               NumberLong(7908625612800033),
               NumberLong(7992837734400000),
               NumberLong(8039920435200033),
               NumberLong(8124132556800000),
               NumberLong(8168737996800033),
               NumberLong(8252950118400000),
               NumberLong(8297555558400033),
               NumberLong(8381767680000000),
               NumberLong(8426373120000033),
               NumberLong(8510585241600000),
               NumberLong(8555190681600033),
               NumberLong(8639402803200000),
               NumberLong(8684008243200033),
               NumberLong(8768220364800000)
            ],
            "offsets":[  
               -28800000,
               -25200000,
               3600000
            ],
            "simpleTimeZoneParams":[  
               2,
               8,
               -1,
               7200000,
               0,
               10,
               1,
               -1,
               7200000,
               0
            ],
            "willGMTOffsetChange":false,
            "dirty":false,
            "ID":"America/Los_Angeles"
         },
         "zoneOffset":0,
         "daylightSaving":0,
         "forceStandardTime":false
      },
      "calsys":{  
         "_class":"sun.util.calendar.Gregorian"
      },
      "zoneOffsets":[  
         -28800000,
         3600000
      ],
      "cachedFixedDate":NumberLong(736765),
      "fields":[  
         1,
         2018,
         2,
         11,
         3,
         12,
         71,
         2,
         2,
         0,
         9,
         9,
         40,
         38,
         897,
         -28800000,
         3600000
      ],
      "isSet":[  
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true,
         true
      ],
      "stamp":[  
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1,
         1
      ],
      "time":NumberLong(1520872838897),
      "isTimeSet":true,
      "areFieldsSet":true,
      "areAllFieldsSet":true,
      "lenient":true,
      "zone":{  
         "_class":"sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo",
         "rawOffset":-28800000,
         "rawOffsetDiff":0,
         "checksum":-2115702508,
         "dstSavings":3600000,
         "transitions":[  
            NumberLong(-9048018124800000),
            NumberLong(-6689872281599967),
            NumberLong(-6615569203200000),
            NumberLong(-6561054719999967),
            NumberLong(-6486751641600000),
            NumberLong(-3605328691199967),
            NumberLong(-3135017779200000),
            NumberLong(-2817913651199967),
            NumberLong(-2714237337600000),
            NumberLong(-2542937702399967),
            NumberLong(-2490929971200000),
            NumberLong(-2414120140799967),
            NumberLong(-2359635148800000),
            NumberLong(-2285302579199967),
            NumberLong(-2230817587200000),
            NumberLong(-2156485017599967),
            NumberLong(-2102000025600000),
            NumberLong(-2027667455999967),
            NumberLong(-1973182464000000),
            NumberLong(-1898849894399967),
            NumberLong(-1844364902400000),
            NumberLong(-1767555071999967),
            NumberLong(-1713070080000000),
            NumberLong(-1638737510399967),
            NumberLong(-1584252518400000),
            NumberLong(-1509919948799967),
            NumberLong(-1455434956800000),
            NumberLong(-1381102387199967),
            NumberLong(-1326617395200000),
            NumberLong(-1252284825599967),
            NumberLong(-1197799833600000),
            NumberLong(-1120990003199967),
            NumberLong(-1068982272000000),
            NumberLong(-992172441599967),
            NumberLong(-927778406400000),
            NumberLong(-863354879999967),
            NumberLong(-798960844800000),
            NumberLong(-734537318399967),
            NumberLong(-670143283200000),
            NumberLong(-605719756799967),
            NumberLong(-538848460800000),
            NumberLong(-476902195199967),
            NumberLong(-410030899200000),
            NumberLong(-345607372799967),
            NumberLong(-281213337600000),
            NumberLong(-216789811199967),
            NumberLong(-152395776000000),
            NumberLong(-87972249599967),
            NumberLong(-23578214400000),
            NumberLong(40845312000033),
            NumberLong(105239347200000),
            NumberLong(169662873600033),
            NumberLong(236534169600000),
            NumberLong(300957696000033),
            NumberLong(365351731200000),
            NumberLong(429775257600033),
            NumberLong(494169292800000),
            NumberLong(518956646400033),
            NumberLong(622986854400000),
            NumberLong(665115033600033),
            NumberLong(751804416000000),
            NumberLong(816227942400033),
            NumberLong(883099238400000),
            NumberLong(945045504000033),
            NumberLong(1011916800000000),
            NumberLong(1076340326400033),
            NumberLong(1140734361600000),
            NumberLong(1205157888000033),
            NumberLong(1269551923200000),
            NumberLong(1333975449600033),
            NumberLong(1398369484800000),
            NumberLong(1462793011200033),
            NumberLong(1527187046400000),
            NumberLong(1591610572800033),
            NumberLong(1658481868800000),
            NumberLong(1720428134400033),
            NumberLong(1787299430400000),
            NumberLong(1851722956800033),
            NumberLong(1916116992000000),
            NumberLong(1980540518400033),
            NumberLong(2044934553600000),
            NumberLong(2109358080000033),
            NumberLong(2173752115200000),
            NumberLong(2230743859200033),
            NumberLong(2302569676800000),
            NumberLong(2359561420800033),
            NumberLong(2433864499200000),
            NumberLong(2488378982400033),
            NumberLong(2562682060800000),
            NumberLong(2617196544000033),
            NumberLong(2691499622400000),
            NumberLong(2748491366400033),
            NumberLong(2820317184000000),
            NumberLong(2877308928000033),
            NumberLong(2949134745600000),
            NumberLong(3006126489600033),
            NumberLong(3080429568000000),
            NumberLong(3134944051200033),
            NumberLong(3209247129600000),
            NumberLong(3263761612800033),
            NumberLong(3338064691200000),
            NumberLong(3395056435200033),
            NumberLong(3466882252800000),
            NumberLong(3523873996800033),
            NumberLong(3595699814400000),
            NumberLong(3652691558400033),
            NumberLong(3724517376000000),
            NumberLong(3781509120000033),
            NumberLong(3855812198400000),
            NumberLong(3910326681600033),
            NumberLong(3984629760000000),
            NumberLong(4039144243200033),
            NumberLong(4113447321600000),
            NumberLong(4170439065600033),
            NumberLong(4242264883200000),
            NumberLong(4299256627200033),
            NumberLong(4371082444800000),
            NumberLong(4428074188800033),
            NumberLong(4502377267200000),
            NumberLong(4556891750400033),
            NumberLong(4631194828800000),
            NumberLong(4685709312000033),
            NumberLong(4760012390400000),
            NumberLong(4807095091200033),
            NumberLong(4891307212800000),
            NumberLong(4935912652800033),
            NumberLong(5020124774400000),
            NumberLong(5064730214400033),
            NumberLong(5148942336000000),
            NumberLong(5196025036800033),
            NumberLong(5280237158400000),
            NumberLong(5324842598400033),
            NumberLong(5409054720000000),
            NumberLong(5453660160000033),
            NumberLong(5537872281600000),
            NumberLong(5582477721600033),
            NumberLong(5666689843200000),
            NumberLong(5711295283200033),
            NumberLong(5795507404800000),
            NumberLong(5840112844800033),
            NumberLong(5924324966400000),
            NumberLong(5971407667200033),
            NumberLong(6055619788800000),
            NumberLong(6100225228800033),
            NumberLong(6184437350400000),
            NumberLong(6229042790400033),
            NumberLong(6313254912000000),
            NumberLong(6357860352000033),
            NumberLong(6442072473600000),
            NumberLong(6486677913600033),
            NumberLong(6570890035200000),
            NumberLong(6617972736000033),
            NumberLong(6702184857600000),
            NumberLong(6746790297600033),
            NumberLong(6831002419200000),
            NumberLong(6875607859200033),
            NumberLong(6959819980800000),
            NumberLong(7004425420800033),
            NumberLong(7088637542400000),
            NumberLong(7133242982400033),
            NumberLong(7217455104000000),
            NumberLong(7262060544000033),
            NumberLong(7346272665600000),
            NumberLong(7393355366400033),
            NumberLong(7477567488000000),
            NumberLong(7522172928000033),
            NumberLong(7606385049600000),
            NumberLong(7650990489600033),
            NumberLong(7735202611200000),
            NumberLong(7779808051200033),
            NumberLong(7864020172800000),
            NumberLong(7908625612800033),
            NumberLong(7992837734400000),
            NumberLong(8039920435200033),
            NumberLong(8124132556800000),
            NumberLong(8168737996800033),
            NumberLong(8252950118400000),
            NumberLong(8297555558400033),
            NumberLong(8381767680000000),
            NumberLong(8426373120000033),
            NumberLong(8510585241600000),
            NumberLong(8555190681600033),
            NumberLong(8639402803200000),
            NumberLong(8684008243200033),
            NumberLong(8768220364800000)
         ],
         "offsets":[  
            -28800000,
            -25200000,
            3600000
         ],
         "simpleTimeZoneParams":[  
            2,
            8,
            -1,
            7200000,
            0,
            10,
            1,
            -1,
            7200000,
            0
         ],
         "willGMTOffsetChange":false,
         "dirty":false,
         "ID":"America/Los_Angeles"
      },
      "sharedZone":false,
      "firstDayOfWeek":1,
      "minimalDaysInFirstWeek":1,
      "nextStamp":2,
      "serialVersionOnStream":1
   }
```

Comment: why you use Calendar object for createdAt, you can use `DateTime` instead of Calendar and then you can easily query on that